# Wordpress exclude child from child page listing

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to exclude certain child pages from the sidebar page listing. This is the code I have:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('order=ASC&title_li=&depth=3&child_of=41&exclude=247'); ?>
```

It lists all children under ID 41 but does not exclude the child ID 247. Anyone knows how to get this code right?

Answer (score 0):

I have code doing exactly thesame thing that works

```
wp_list_pages('child_of=4&depth=2&exclude=89');
```

The only thing I can think of is maybe 247 doesnt exist or isnt the page you think it is, I'd also remove the

> title_li=

since it's blank.

Comment: A black title_li indicates they don't want a title, that's the only way to do it with this function.

Comment: The page does exist and I tried to exclude another page with no success. It seems to me that you can't exclude from a children list.

Comment: Well maybe you can take a look @ the source code for wp_list_pages and see exactly what it is doing... or you could use a css solution which hides the generated menu item based on the auto-generated class names

page-item-247 { display: none; }